# Programmatically Populate Schema

Tags: solr, admin-pages

I would like to create a custom aspx page to populate Solr schema akin to how you create a custom aspx page to rebuild indexes (https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/rebuild-search-indexes.html)

This is part of a larger PaaS deployment automation so I will not be using the endpoint that you can use to populate schema as that requires logging into Sitecore first (https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/solr-managed-schemas.html)

Is there a good way to create a custom aspx page for calling a populate schema akin to the example in the Sitecore docs per rebuilding indexes?

I use the Sitecore CLI for my local development but am choosing the custom aspx pages as part of the larger deployment automation for Azure PaaS environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `PopulateManagedSchema.aspx` admin page at `sitecoreinstance\sitecore\admin` folder. When you click on `Populate Solr Managed Schema` link under the control panel, select the indexes checkbox and hit `Populate` button, under the hood it triggers the `PopulateManagedSchema.aspx` page load method to populate schema. Here you will see the populate schema code. It is part of `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.dll`

If you want some custom implementation then you can try out to create a custom aspx page and use any decompiler tool to understand and see the code `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.dll` you will find this code at `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.sitecore.admin.PopulateManagedSchema` and customize as per your requirement.

You need to mainly use this piece of code:

```
try
{
    bool flag = text2.ToLower().Equals("all");
    Log.Audit("Start Populating Managed Schema from Admin Page, indexes: " + string.Join(", ", list.ToArray()), this);
    foreach (ISearchIndex index in ContentSearchManager.Indexes)
    {
        if (flag || list.Contains(index.Name.ToLower()))
        {
            SchemaCustodian.PopulateManagedSchema(index);
        }
    }
    stringBuilder.Append(" OK<br/>");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(string.Concat("<textarea class='exception'>", ex, "</textarea><br/>"));
}
```

You can validate it directly like, if you call it with URL and pass '|' index names it would update the managed-schema and then you can check at solr folder.

```
https://yourSitecoreInstance/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=sitecore_master_index|test_products_master_index
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I pulled that and need it outside the admin page. I may move it to the root and invoke a web request